Conditional aggregation in SQL: display condition-dependent count in percentage?
I am doing a portfolio project and I have a table that looks like this:



Customer_ID
Churn_Label
Gender




1
No
Male


2
Yes
Female


3
Yes
Male



I want to display the percentage of churn by gender but I only know how to display the count.
SELECT Gender, count(*)
FROM customer_churn
WHERE churn_value = 1
GROUP BY Gender;

I tried conditional aggregation but I can't figure it out because I need the percentage total to be the total churn count (1869), not the total customer count (7043). What I tried to say in the title is that the count I'm trying to convert to percentage of total is created by a WHERE condition like WHERE churn_label = 'Yes' so I when I tried conditional aggregation I didn't know how to do it.
I want my results to look like that:



Gender
Churn_pct




Male
49.8%


Female
50.2%



I would appreciate any help in how to approach this.
Thank you

Use a window count function , this allows you to access all rows and get the total count of churns

Sample data and desired result that don''t match isn't very helpful.


I want to display the percentage of churn by gender but I only know how to display the count.

Use SUM OVERto get the total count and do the calculation:
SELECT gender, COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS churn_pct
FROM customer_churn
WHERE churn_value = 1
GROUP BY gender
ORDER BY gender DESC;


I'm grateful for you @Thorsten!! I was breaking my head over this :)
